# Changing date formats in PHP < 5.3.0

Tags: php, datetime

Given a date string in the format m-d-Y (e.g, "12-09-2011") how can I display it in the format "m/d/Y" **WITHOUT** resorting to regular expressions.

Just in case you missed it: ***without using regular expressions.***

I would prefer to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` for this problem, but the server I am using currently doesn't have 5.3.0 on it.

I'd also prefer using `date('m/d/Y', strtotime("12-09-2011"))` but `strtotime()` doesn't recognize that format properly. It confuses the day and month.

Comment: Regex is not necessary, you can use string manipulation (`strpos() substr()`, etc), but perhaps you intended to restrict those as well?

Comment: After seeing a similar question in the related posts (didn't show up when I was typing this question), it looks like this isn't possible without regex.

Comment: Michael, you're correct. Looks like thats what I'd have to do, though. PHP before 5.3 is awful, lol.

Comment: @ChrisG. This is definitely possible with or without regex. Very simple string parsing is all that's required (as shown by MarcB)

Comment: Where are you getting your initial date from (12-09-2011)? If it's from MySQL then you could convert it to a timestamp instead.

Comment: It is working on my machine. Whats the wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for heavy artillery. Since you're not rearranging the date components, a simple [string search/replace](http://php.net/str_replace) will do:

```
$string = '12-09-2011';
$fixed = str_replace('-', '/', $string);
```

If you WERE rearrangine things, e.g. durning your m-d-Y into d/m/y, then you'd need something a bit heavier:

```
$string = '12-09-2011';
$parts = explode('-', $string); // array(0 => '12', 1 => '09', 2 => '2011');
$fixed = $parts[1] . '/' . $parts[0] . '/' . $parts[2]; // 09/12/2011
```

Comment: Of course I could do this, I should have mentioned I am familiar with string parsing as well as regex. What I was asking is if PHP had a built-in function prior to the 5.3.0 implementation of the `DateTime` class. Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: It's in php 5.1 but flagged as experimental, so not enabled by default: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.installation.php   Prior to that, you're probably SOL, unless someone's got an unofficial backport somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisG. I'm not following. You want a PHP function from the base library that will perform `DateTime::createFromFormat()` in a pre 5.3 environment? Why go through all the trouble of explaining that you can't use regex? Are you looking for someone to create this function but without regex?

Comment: Because if I didn't I'd have 50 answers with regex in it. No I wasnt asking if someone would make a function that did it for me. I simply wanted to know if how to "do it rite" in a 5.3 environment that didn't have a DateTime class.

Answer (score 1):

What about exploding it? i.e.

```
$date = explode('-',  "12-09-2011");
echo $date[1] . '/' . $date[0] . '/' . $date[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sscanf("12-09-2011", "%d-%d-%d", $month, $day, $year);
echo "$month/$day/$year";
```